# How to look for Bounce rate per pageview using Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to look for a query that tells me the bounce rate per highest pageview on the website, using google BigQuery.

This is what I tried so far, but this bounce rate does not match with what I see in Google Analytics:

**standardSQL**

```
SELECT
  hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath,
  COUNT(*) AS pageViews,
  (COUNT(totals.bounces)/COUNT(totals.visits))*100 AS bounceRate
FROM
  `GA.1234567.ga_sessions_*` AS GA,
  UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190301'
  AND '20190705'
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
GROUP BY
  hits.page.pagePath
ORDER BY
  pageViews DESC,
  bounceRate
LIMIT
  1000
```

I expect the output of bounce rate to be equal to what I see on GA (shown in `"Behaviour" --> "Site content" --> "All Pages"`) but the current query shows a completely different number.

Could you give me solutions for this?

Comment: I believe your query is looking at all pages, whereas Bounce Rate is usually for landing pages only.

Comment: Yes, I want to look up bounce rate per pages since Google Analytics allows to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't limit to landing pages.  Assume you have pages `/stuff` and `/things`.  If someone arrives from Google and lands on `/stuff`, they can click through to other pages or they can bounce.  Assume they then click through to `/things`.  They cannot bounce from `/things` in this case, because it is not their first page in the session.  However, if they arrive at `/things` from Google, then they could bounce.  Your query is looking at page hits, even if they aren't the 1st page hit of a session.  This is making your denominator too large.  You will want to find the id of the first PAGE hit in a session, then join back to your sessions/hits table.

I would read [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009409?hl=en) before proceeding.